# How to make a grouped stacked chart in Excel? (see picture)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-chart

How do I make a chart like the one below here?

[image]

Comment: It would help if you provided a file with sample data and possibly an existing chart. That could be saved in OneDrive or DropBox and a view link posted here. -- Please specify the version of Excel you are using; it could make a difference.

Comment: Try to provide a sample about your requirement, it will be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will see what I can do

Comment: I have written a tutorial about this: [Clustered and Stacked Column and Bar Charts](https://peltiertech.com/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/).